# Pyqt5 : PasswordEdit not found in QtWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a pyqt application on Windows, i m trying to make a password field using PasswordEdit libary but it s missing in the QtWidgets Folder, i tried to upgrade qtwidgets using pip but i couldn't.
Any Solution?

Comment: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum

Comment: What is "PasswordEdit library"? It doesn't exist such a thing in Qt.

Comment: The link doesn't help too much. And PasswordEdit exists, you can check on https://www.learnpyqt.com/widgets/passwordedit/

Comment: Or this one https://pypi.org/project/qtwidgets/

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't exist, but that is *not* part of Qt. That is a *custom* library. if you cannot install that from pip, just download it from the [repository](https://github.com/learnpyqt/python-qtwidgets) and copy the `qtwidgets` directory to your project folder.

Comment: I tried to add it but it s in a different format, it didn't work, also i didn't find a tutorial explaining how to add it to QtWidgets

Answer (score 2):

PasswordEdit does not belong to Qt but to an external library called [`qtwidgets`](https://pypi.org/project/qtwidgets/) that uses Qt underneath, so you have to install it using:

```
python -m pip install qtwidgets
```

and then:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from qtwidgets import PasswordEdit


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        password = PasswordEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(password)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```